# Can Tableau send the WMS GetFeatureInfo request back to WMS server?

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, wms, tableau-api

I am deploying my own custom WMS, but I am having some issue to use WMS server in tableau other than show it as a background

**Question 1**: Can tableau send the WMS getFeatureInfo request back when user click the pixel on the WMS background map?

**Question 2**: Does tableau have the capability to take parameterized WMS URL?

for example:
Is there anyway to input or replace the parameter "**year**" and "**month**" on tableau side.

**Question 3**: Can tableau do more things with WMS server, other than switch map layers and show maps as static beautiful background image?

Anything could help, thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What resources have you looked at? Also, questions are limited to one question that you're struggling with where you post everything you've got and people help you from there. This is a series of related questions, and should be edited to only be the first question.

Comment: Can't you see all the questions are the same issue? answer one will answer all of them. I have tried latest tableau with all different kinds of wms server, but I am not able to do anything else other than showing the maps and changes layers.

Answer (score 1):

OK, just spoke to Tableau tech person face to face, the answers are NO to all my questions.
WMS server for tableau, Background image only!!! nothing more, no parameters, no https, no pixel click request.